# Volume control sometimes stuck on MBP '18

Tags: macbook-pro, sound-volume, touch-bar

My 2018 MacBook Pro is sometimes suffering from 'sticky' volume control.

When I am interacting with the volume controls on the Touch Bar for a longer period of time, the volume control gets stuck sometimes. The sound is then automatically, continuously being muted or (with a bit of bad luck) set to full volume. During this time, the adjustment popup remains constantly visible.

Only when I go mach five on the Touch bar and press all the volume buttons in random order (haven't been able to find a pattern), the OS surrenders and I regain control over the volume.

It usually occurs once or twice every week. It also occurred on a clean install, so third-party apps acting strange is out of the question.

Is this a known problem? Is there a permanent solution?

Comment: Same problem. Randomly taping all the controls as you suggest did fix it. Really annoying. Killing the ControlStrip or reseting the Touch Bar agent did not help. MBP 18 as well (15")

Comment: I had it a couple of times and it sucks a lot. Same solution with mach five.

Comment: I have it all the time, it started a couple of months ago. I wonder if this is a software bug in an application, in some OS update or whether it's a hardware issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, restart your MacBookPro

If this doesn't work than try reinstalling macOS by booting into recovery mode by pressing command+r while startup, select "reinstall macOS". I recommend doing a backup first even you won't loose any of your files and settings.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue periodically. I refresh the touch bar by switching apps (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>).